# Search the last comment in a many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, max

I have 3 tables :

Post, PostComment and Comment.

It's a many-to-many relation.

I want to select for each post the last comment.
So something like (select * from comment order by create_at DESC limit 1) doest not work here.

And I want something like:

```
select *
  from post as p
    left join post_comment as pc on (pc.post_id = p.id)
    left joint comment as c on (c.id = pc.comment_id)
    left joint comment as c2 on (c2.id = pc.comment_id and c2.id > c.id)
  where c2.id is null
```

It works very well for one-to-many relation, but I can't get ride of this for many-to-many.

Note: I renamed my table. In my code, I do not use comment and post. And I do need a many-to-many relation.

Thanks you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: If you use an ORM, then maybe tag your question with which ORM and which language. Perhaps you'll get the exact answer you need.

Comment: OK, I will tag it Doctrine2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that :

```
select *
  from post as p
    left join post_comment as pc on (pc.post_id = p.id)
    left join comment as c on (c.id = pc.comment_id)
    left outer join
            (post_comment as pc2
                inner join comment as c2 on (c2.id = pc2.comment_id)
            ) on (bc2.post_id = p.id and c1.created_at < c2.created_at)
  where c2.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

the  main table on your query should be postcomment and you can group by postid and get the max(postcomment) assuming it is an autoincrementid.

then you just join the result with the other tables to get the rest of the data.
Since you probably have a lot of data you need from the other tables and to avoid adding all these data to the group by, I would use a CTE:

(CTE is a sql server syntax, if you are not using sql server you'll have to use another mechanism to store this temporary data)

```
with my_cte as
(
    select idpost, max(idcomment)  as last_comment_id
    from postcomment pc 
    group by idpost
)
select *
from my_cte 
     join post p on p.idpost=my_cte.idpost
     join comment c on c.idcomment=my_cte.last_comment_id
```

Comment: I use an orm. So I prefere avoir `with` statement. but Thanks.